# Cannot center table on PDF-page when saving a matplotib table using backend_pdf PdfPages

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, pdfpages

I can generate a matplotlib table (without any visibly associated plot) in a jupyter notebook, but when I try to save it to a PDF using matplotlib's internal `backend_pdf.PdfPages` wrapper, it never appears centered on a page.

I've tried messing with `'top'`,`'center'`,`'bottom'`, and offsets and `savefig(pad_inches)` to no avail. Here's my example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

col_names = ["this", "that","the other","4","5","6"]
page_data = np.random.randint(100, size=(40,6))

# stringify numbers: tables can't have ints in them.
for idx, sub in enumerate(page_data):
    page_data[idx] = [str(i) for i in sub]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,8))
axs.axis('off')
_table = plt.table(
    cellText=page_data,
    colLabels=col_names,
    loc='top',
    edges='open',
    colLoc='right')

# and now, the PDF doesn't fit on page    
pdf = PdfPages('test.pdf')
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

My intuition is that there is still an invisible figure taking up space, and that's pushing up all the content on my page. How do I obliterate that figure, or size it to zero and only PDF the table text?

screenshot of PDF output:
[image]

screenshot of Jupyter output (note the large blank space after table)
[image]

Comment: I noticed that my original code said `plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))` but William has edited to `plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,8))`. Both appear to work the same in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loc='center'` should solve this issue, and for the minimal example in question it does,

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

col_names = ["this", "that","the other","4","5","6"]
data = np.random.randint(100, size=(40,6)).astype('str')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
ax.axis('off')
_table = plt.table(cellText=data, colLabels=col_names, 
                   loc='center', edges='open', colLoc='right')

pdf = PdfPages('test.pdf')
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

[image]

It is important to note however, that this will position the table in the 'center' relative to the current `Axes` instance. It is probably safer to use the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.table` version if you are using multiple subplots since it allows finer control of which `Axes` is used.

---

**Note**   -   I have tested this in Matplotlib 2.2.5 and 3.2.1, if the code above does produce the result I have shown, consider updating your Matplotlib installation.

Comment: Huh. Well, it does seem to resolve this issue. I tried `loc='center'` in one of my iterations and something else must have been different because it didn't resolve the issue at that time.

As for a secondary issue, the last page of this multi page report only has a few entries and it looks weird in the center of the page. But That works with `loc='top'` so I think I can resolve it with some logic.